# Realm React Native disable debugging only for Realm

Tags: android, ios, react-native, realm

I am trying to use Realm in my application. Since this issue exists and will not be fixed for the foreseeable future (https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/491), I am not able to put debug debug mode in React Native and I am searching for a way to debug the rest of the application. Note that the data I need to store is really big.

Is there a way either on iOS or Android to disable debug mode *only* on Realm, but still keep debugging the rest of the application using the chrome debugger?

I have tried debugging using Reactotron logs or any other method, but not being able to put a breakpoint in my application is really bad.